# Dynamically generated element with Angular method not being called

Tags: angular

I have a method that generates a set of svg's automatically and injects them into my body:

```js
async generateRandomTextItems(count: number): Promise<string[]> {
  const availableFontResponses = [];
  const allAvailableFonts = this.fontsService.fonts.getValue();
  const allAvailableTerms = UtilService.LEFT_WORDS;

  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    let availableFontResponse = await this.generateSvgPathResponse(
      allAvailableFonts,
      allAvailableTerms
    );
    if (this.isValidFontResponse(availableFontResponse)) {
      availableFontResponse = availableFontResponse.replace('<svg', '<svg class="draggable" onload="makeDraggable(evt)"');
      availableFontResponse = availableFontResponse.replace('null', '');
      availableFontResponses.push(availableFontResponse);
    }
  }
  return availableFontResponses;
}
```

I render the svg's within a div in the following way:

```html
<div
  class="sidebar-text-container"
  *ngFor="let randomTextItem of randomTextItems"
  [@fadeIn]
>
  <div [innerHTML]="randomTextItem | safeHtml"></div>
</div>
```

Each svg has an `onload` method that needs to be called from the component's controller:

```html
<svg
  class="draggable"
  onload="makeDraggable(evt)"
  width="94.5"
  height="18.176"
  viewBox="0 0 94.5 18.176"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>
  ...
</svg>
```

i.e.

```js
export class BuilderSidebarTextComponent { 
   makeDraggable() {
     console.log('hello');
   }
}
```

However, this method is never called. It doesn't seem to be recognised by the injected element. How do I fix this?

Comment: The load event has happened before component was initialised, I believe you should move this logic in ngAfterViewInit

Answer (score 1):

The `onload` event you are binding to inline, is fired before the component is instantiated and initialised so no component class method can react to it.
(the same is valid for `load` event).

To avoid this and also keep your logic out of the html, you should be defining this svg initialisation code within the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle method, which is fired after the component template is initialised and you can have access to it's view children, in a way similar to this:

Template (many svgs):

```
<svg height="210" width="500" #svgs></svg>
<svg height="210" width="500" #svgs></svg>
```

Component:

```
@ViewChildren('svgs') svgs: QueryList<ElementRef<SVGAElement>>;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.svgs.map(svg => svg.nativeElement.style.height = '50')
}
```

[An example in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wveoc4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Note: even if it was a valid case to use `load` event, it would be much better imho to use  `@HostListener('load', ['$event'])` inside the class or in a directive, whichever makes sense to your use case, to keep logic where it belongs and only have bindings in your template.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try making your `onload` -> `(load)` ? This should work if you are using Angular